# How to use vm-bhyve image create?

Tags: freebsd, zfs, bhyve

As per the [Documentation](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=vm&sektion=8&manpath=freebsd-release-ports) it will create a new image from the named virtual machine you pass. It should look like this:

```
vm image create -u VMNAME
```

After executing that command as `root` I get this error:

```
vm: ERROR: failed to create snapshot of source dataset root/vm/VMNAME@gdee65d
```

I found no information or similar problem.

Update: The goal here is to create an image/iso file of a running vm and migrate it to a cloud, which accepts only custom iso files.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, You need to have ZFS for using `vm image` commands.
[vm(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=vm&sektion=8&manpath=FreeBSD+13.1-RELEASE+and+Ports)

> Please note that these commands rely on using ZFS features   to
> package/unpackage the images, and as such are only available when
> using a ZFS dataset as the storage location.

Your error happens because of this line in `vm-bhyve` script:

https://github.com/churchers/vm-bhyve/blob/master/lib/vm-zfs#L365

```bash
# try to snapshot
zfs snapshot -r "${VM_DS_ZFS_DATASET}/${_name}@${_snap}" >/dev/null 2>&1
[ $? -eq 0 ] || util::err "failed to create snapshot of source dataset ${VM_DS_ZFS_DATASET}/${_name}@${_snap}"
```

It will try to create a ZFS snapshot from your image, And seems like you do not have any dataset with `root/vm/` name.

define your ZFS dataset in `/etc/rc.conf` with:

```bash
sysrc vm_dir="YOUR_ZFS_DATASET/vm"
```

**How to create an image/iso file of a running vm?**

You can convert zfs to a raw file with:

```bash
dd if=/dev/zvol/zvol_name of=/mnt/tank/path/file.img
```

Then convert it to any type of vm disk file you want with qemu-utils!
For example for `vmdk`:

```bash
qemu-img convert -O vmdk <vmname>.raw <vmname>.vmdk
```

Comment: I've tried the dd utility, but it creates a full copy if the disk, even the empty space. I have been searching for solution that is kind of straight forward.

Comment: @Baequiraheal If I understand your problem correctly, You need ISO format of your vm. The IMG format files are compatible with ISO format. You can find your vm disk image at the `vm_dir` location and directly use it.